# how to add uiscollview in uicontainor view

Tags: ios

> hi all i am in trouble for my app layout, i want to add scrollview in uicontainor view, i even don't know it is possible or i have to move some other solution.

[image: This is my screen shot of my problem]

> i want to scroll view in my child view of container view, now i have not idea how to do it.
>
> this is the code which i use to switch view form th uisegmentcontroll.

```
- (IBAction)segmentcontrol:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:(0.5) animations:^{
        self.secondview.alpha = 1;
        self.firstview.alpha = 0;
    }];
} else {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:(0.5) animations:^{
        self.secondview.alpha = 0;
        self.firstview.alpha = 1;
    }];
}
```

}

> please someone help me, i am editing my question with new layout which i used now.

[image: This is my structure, here i am add a uiscrollview in child view controller]

Comment: Give me some hint please about this problem

Answer (score 0):

As you already have `containerView` you should make `Embed` controller to it and you have this already too. Imagine that you want scrollView to be on the `viewController` where you have `Label` located, First step is to drag & drop scrollView controller on your viewController and if you want something inside scrollview you can add it inside.

Comment: Thanks, so i need to uiscrollview inside the view controller where i located a label?.

Comment: I said label for example. Uiviewcontroller and on it you should add scrollview